# What is apache-Kafka and camel-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am starting to learn about Apache Kafka. This https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/intra-cluster-replication-apache-kafka article states that Kafka is a CA system inside the CAP-Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel is an Enterprise Integration Pattern (EIP) framework. Camel-Kafka is a plugin for it; it is a JVM Kafka client. It has nothing to do with CAP Theorem.

Apache Kafka is a message broker server. You are not required to use Camel with it.